# &new MyClass() vs new MyClass() in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any difference between the following?

```
$myVar=&new MyClass();
$myVar=new MyClass();
```

I am coding in PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using PHP5, there is no difference.

If using PHP4, the former passes a reference to the new object.

> This is because "new" does not return a reference by default, instead it returns a copy.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/pl/oop4.newref.php).

[Give this a read, too](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2004/07/15/php-5-object-references/).

Comment: In PHP4, what difference will having a reference to the new object make?

Comment: @Casebash: PHP4 copies object instances instead of passing references by default. `&` is the *reference* operator.

Answer (score 3):

Using PHP5? Then you should use the following:

```
$myVar=new MyClass();
```

This is the accepted way to initialize a class.

---

Using the following when `E_STRICT` is enabled:

```
$myVar=&new MyClass();
```

will cause the PHP runtimes to raise the warning `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated`.

Comment: @Casebash: It is just a hint that the behaviour has changed from the previous major version and that the behaviour is now implicit I guess.

Comment: @Casebash: It's deprecated behavior. There is no reason in PHP5 why you would put `&` in front of an instance initialization.

Answer (score 0):

`&new` has been removed from PHP7, you have to use `new` instead.

> Assignment of new by reference
>
> Since PHP 5.3 assignment of new expressions by references is
>   deprecated. It can be replaced with a normal assignment 1):
>
> // Instead of $obj =& new ClassName;
>
> // Write $obj = new ClassName;
>
> Assigning the return value by reference is no longer necessary since
>   PHP 5.0.

Check this thread https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7